# jQuery- how .click() works with function identifier passed as argument?

Tags: jquery

```
$('button').click(function(){ console.log('works'); });
```

This outputs 'works' when I click the required button.

But if I pack the same code in a function and call it with parentheses attached to it(as you usually invoke a function), as in

```
function worker(){ console.log('works'); }
$('button').click(worker());
```

*worker* gets fired without any click on *button*. But if I avoid the parentheses, as in

```
function worker(){ console.log('works'); }
$('button').click(worker);
```

I'm getting the desired functionality. Why the *click* handler behaves this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a function in JavaScript *without* parenthesis, what you are doing is **assigning** the actual function. This does not immediately execute the function.

When you call a function in JavaScript *with* parenthesis, you are **executing** the function immediately and returning the value of that function.

Having said that, if you had a function that returned a function itself, you could in-fact call a function, whose return value would then be another function. (*Generally not advised*)

To address your comment:
Suppose you write the following statement: `$('button').click(console.log('works'));`
The result would be that as soon as your page is loaded, "works" will be printed to the console. This is because `console.log()` is a function being called *with* parenthesis.

However, if you did the following approach:

```
var worksFunc = function() {console.log('works')};
$('button').click(worksFunc);
```

It will now reference the function for execution on the `click` event.

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/9EEkA75vJbzKw0T1euqI)**

Comment: understood. but what a statement such as `$('button').click(console.log('works'))`, does?

Comment: @KameswaranGanesh It is going to immediately log `works` to your console. This is because `console.log()` is a **function** itself. When you call it with parenthesis, you are going to immediately execute that function.

Comment: understood. Thank you @EvanBechtol

Comment: @KameswaranGanesh I updated my answer for you with example :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't pass the function object with `worker()`, the brackets let it execut directly. Removing the brackes will let you pass the reference to the function by the name `worker`.

Maybe it is clearer if you look at it this way:

```
var worker = function() { console.log('works'); }
$('button').click(worker);
```